# SQL "SCRIPT" command to backup h2 database

Tags: java, sql, h2

I have an application with `h2` database. I want to create `.sql` file using `SCRIPT` command in Java.

If I am executing it using Prepared Statement:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("SCRIPT");
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

Then how can I able to get whole result in single String. I am new to Java so unable to find the way out to get result of that query because it doesn't contains column names in it.

Then I will write it in file using `InputStream`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to **backup** into a file, the content of your `H2` instance as a **SQL script**, you can directly use [`SCRIPT TO 'path/to/my/file.sql'`](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#script).

```
try (Connection con = ...;
     Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
    stmt.executeQuery(String.format("SCRIPT TO '%s'", sqlFilePath));
}
```

---

If you want to **backup** it as **a ZIP archive**, you can use [`BACKUP TO 'path/to/my/file.zip'`](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#backup).

```
try (Connection con = ...;
     Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
    stmt.executeQuery(String.format("BACKUP TO '%s'", zipFilePath));
}
```

Comment: Ok now i got idea on how to move it to file. Will try it and update.

Comment: It works fine but stmt.executeUpdate needs to be replaced with stmt.executeQuery

Comment: Maybe I am doing somethig wrong, but after creation execute this statemtent and only get one file with "CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS "SA" SALT '4d7ed4bf3238b907' HASH '8326f36da8ddeddb5edb065ad2b6ac59536448f26d99ebf8c3c70e8c018a877d' ADMIN;"  But I know that exist tables and other objects in database.....any help?