# Schedule automatic SQL script run in Spring with H2

Tags: java, spring, h2

I have a Spring application with H2 database. I would like to schedule automatic backups of DB, currently I'm doing it by opening H2 console and running `SCRIPT TO`. This does exactly what I need, but I have to do it maunally.

Is there a way to do this automatically with `Scheduled` annotation, from application?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40592133/sql-script-command-to-backup-h2-database

Comment: Thank you, somehow I missed that question.

Comment: Closing as duplicate then ;)